# Flask run command not respecting config file env var

Tags: python, flask

When I call flask run, the app itself is not respecting my local env configuration. Im expecting the environment to be in debug mode and development, but the console output says otherwise

```
flask run
* Serving Flask app "flaskr/app.py"
* Environment: production
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
<Config {'ENV': 'development', 'DEBUG': True, 'TESTING': False, 
'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION': None, 
'SECRET_KEY': 'this-really-needs-to-be-changed', 
'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 
'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 
'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 
'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 
'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 
'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 
'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200), 
'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 
'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 
'JSON_AS_ASCII': True, 'JSON_SORT_KEYS': True, 
'JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR': False, 'JSONIFY_MIMETYPE': 
'application/json', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093, 'CSRF_ENABLED': True, 'DEVELOPMENT': True}>
```

config.py file

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'this-really-needs-to-be-changed'


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False


class StagingConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    ENV = 'development'
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True


class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

app.py file

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
logger = app.logger


print(app.config)
```

Am i missing something or misunderstanding how the Flask CLI works?

Comment: Hi, what's the value of your environment variable: APP_SETTINGS? This is where your flask app is loading it's config setting from.

Comment: @NathanWright its "config.DevelopmentConfig".  its actually just instantiating the object from the config file

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to see what configuration your application was trying to instantiate based on that environment variable. Can you change the APP_SETTINGS variable to just: DevelopmentConfig? Your ProductionConfig, DevelopmentConfig, and TestingConfig are inheriting from your base Config so you shouldn't need to say "config.DevelopmentConfig"

Comment: @NathanWright got it In my .env file, im doing `export APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"` then passing that to the from_object function. Ill give your suggestion a try and see where it goes

Comment: Do you have a `.env` file that has `APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"` set? Also, you need to install python-dotenv for flask to look for the .env file.